# Zabbix login with php

Tags: php, zabbix

I have written a simple test page which logins to Zabbix server using the API Provided in https://github.com/confirm-it-solutions/PhpZabbixApi/releases

Below is the code i have written.

```
    <?php
// load ZabbixApi
require_once 'build/ZabbixApi.class.php';
use ZabbixApi\ZabbixApi;

try
{
    // connect to Zabbix API
    $api = new ZabbixApi('http://xxx.xxx.xxx/zabbix/', 'credit', 'debit','','');

    /* ... do your stuff here ... */
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
    echo"In Exception <br/>";
    // Exception in ZabbixApi catched
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

and below is the error i am getting.
"In Exception Could not decode JSON response"

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing `/api_jsonrpc.php` in your URL.

Answer (score 1):

> PhpZabbixApi is generated directly from the origin Zabbix™ 2.0 PHP

You use Zabbix 2.4, where login method is slightly different - Zabbix 2.0 login method -> Zabbix 2.4 doesn't understand 2.0 call, so it returns HTML instead of JSON -> PHP API has a problem.

Build your PhpZabbixApi 2.4 version and it should be OK - https://github.com/confirm-it-solutions/PhpZabbixApi#building

OT: You are open - you have published your URL and your admin credentials :-)

Comment: - Jan thanks for help. I am very new to PHP. Do you have any idea how to build PhpZabbixApi 2.4?

Comment: @PradeepVempati: API provides how to -  https://github.com/confirm-it-solutions/PhpZabbixApi#building